# MaxDB SAP SQL Missing keyword WITH on update

Tags: sql, maxdb

Hi there I'm using MaxDB and trying to update a table and I get the error Missing keyword:WITH. Code: -5015.

Here is my SQL:

```
UPDATE agm
SET agm_confirm_stat = 'C',
    agm_confirm_usr = 'MEDICWARE',
    agm_confirm_obs = 'Wellon: Confirmado',
    agm_obs = NVL(agm_obs, '') || '\/\/Wellon: Confirmar',
    agm_confirm_dthr = TIMESTAMP
WHERE (agm_pac = '319900')
    AND (
        agm_obs NOT LIKE '%Wellon: Confirmar%'
        OR agm_obs IS NULL
    )
    AND (agm_str_cod = 'FBC')
    AND (agm_hini = '2022-12-07 08:00:00')
    AND (agm_confirm_stat != 'C')
    AND (agm_stat = 'A')
```

Comment: Use better indentation, at least use sql beautifier.

Comment: Maybe a missing semicolon before or after the statement? Is NVL a valid function with MaxDB?